# Convert Lua array to C array when C function takes multiple inputs

Tags: c++, arrays, c, lua

I'm trying to figure out the interaction between Lua and C where a C function takes multiple inputs, one being a Lua array. Other articles on StackOverflow cover only an array being passed in to C, where the C code uses `-1` to index the array.

**Note 1:** I am not a Lua expert.

**Note 2:** I mentioned that other posts do not cover the complication of indices. I offered a solution below which covers it and makes it clear. Do not flag this without understanding the full context. Many may not like my Note 2, but many users know flagging is an issue.

Lua

```
name = "id string"
random_array = {1.2, 1.3, 1.4}
c_function(name, random_array, 3) -- 3 is the size of array.
```

C

```
static int c_function(lua_State* L)
{
    const char* name = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    int size = luaL_checkinteger(L, 3);
    double data[size];

    // How do I get array values from 'L' into 'data'?

    Calculate(name, data, size);
    return 0;
}

void Calculate(const char* name, double* data, int size)
{
    // Existing function which acts on the data.
    // This function cannot change.
}
```

Comment: Why do the other arguments make a difference? Use the technique in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940366/passing-array-to-c-as-argument-in-the-stack and specify `2` as the argument index for the Lua table.

Comment: You need to use the lua function to get an item out of a table. You can't just convert the Lua table into a C array - you have to keep it as a Lua table and access the items individually. (You can use this to make a C array if you really want to)

Comment: @user253751 - Yes, I am aware of that.

Comment: Two notes: (1) Why pass the size to `c_function` when you could just determine the length of the `random_array` using the appropriate Lua API call (only use cases I could see would be efficient "slicing" up to a length or dealing with sequences with `nil` where the length isn't well defined); (2) stack-allocating the `double` array is problematic. What if `size` is too large for the stack? You should probably heap allocate this instead.

Comment: @Luatic - How do I pass the Lua array in if it's too big? What is the cutoff for `lua_State` stacks?

Comment: @Barmar - I seen that StackOverflow post. They use `-1` instead of `1`. Will `2` work as you suggested? Maybe there's more to the `-1`, I am not skilled in Lua.

Comment: I don't know Lua, but I think the key is `lua_settop(L, 1);` at the beginning. In your case you'd use `lua_settop(L, 2);`

Comment: @Barmar `lua_settop` isn't even strictly needed. If you know which arguments you want, you can just ignore any others by working with negative indices to reference elements from the top of the stack. As you fetch values from the table, they will be pushed to the top of the stack, and can be found at index `-1`. I think the previously linked question effectively has the answer, though, and this a duplicate. Just needs to be adjusted to floating-points. roughly: https://godbolt.org/z/ead9hefns

Comment: @user2205930 the `lua_State` stack shouldn't be the problem. It's about the `double` array you're stack-allocation on the C stack. You should be heap-allocating it.

Comment: @Barmar - I used the link you provided and put an answer below. The trick was getting the indices correct. The post you provided uses `-1` everywhere and it wasn't obvious when and when not to use `-1`. I did not use your suggestion of `lua_settop` because they may pop items, which I didn't want to do. Anyway, I didn't accept my answer because I don't know what proper etiquette is here for creating an answer based on a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link provided by @Barmar and some playing around, below is a working solution for anyone who may run into this problem. Getting the indices correct took some trial-and-error, so hopefully this saves people time in the future. Based on Lua 5.4:

Lua

```
name = "id of entry"
array1 = {1.1, 1.2, 1.3}
array2 = {2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4}

c_function(name, array1, array2)
```

C/C++

```
static int c_function(lua_State* L)
{
    const char* name = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    
    std::vector<double> arr1;
    std::vector<double> arr2;

    // array1 - pay attention to use of 2, -1 and 1.
    if (lua_istable(L, 2) != 0)
    {
        unsigned int size = lua_rawlen(L, 2);
        arr1.resize(size);
        
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            lua_rawgeti(L, 2, i + 1); // Lua uses 1 based indices.
            arr1[i] = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
            lua_pop(L, 1);
        }
    }

    // array2 - pay attention to use of 3, -1 and 1.
    if (lua_istable(L, 3) != 0)
    {
        unsigned int size = lua_rawlen(L, 3);
        arr2.resize(size);
        
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            lua_rawgeti(L, 3, i + 1); // Lua uses 1 based indices.
            arr2[i] = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
            lua_pop(L, 1);
        }
    }

    Calculate(name, arr1, arr2);

    return 0;
}

void Calculate(const char* name, const std::vector<double>& arr1, const std::vector<double>& arr2)
{
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

Comment: This is C++, though. Consider changing your question's tags from [tag:c] to [tag:c++] if that's really the language you are working in, and want answers in.

Comment: @Oka - Perhaps I missed something, where is the C++ outside of the comments?

Comment: Operators: `new` and `delete`. And technically `nullptr`, until [C23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/nullptr).

Comment: @Oka - Ahhh, yeah. I looked right past that.

Comment: Update - I've switched over to C++.

Comment: This looks correct. You can make the array converter into a function so you don't have to write the same code twice. Also maybe think about what you want to do if the argument is not a table, and check what happens if the arguments are missing.